# My adapter id not changes while notifydatasetchanged() also

Tags: android

- I am deleting the item from the array based on the position of the listview.
- I am able to  delete that item from the database but not from the listview immediately.
- I am using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`; for updating but it not working. While using `adapter.clear()` it works fine and clearing the list view.
  I am deleting the item from the array based on the position of the `listview`.
- I am able to  delete that item from the database but not from the listview immediately.  I am using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` for updating but it not working. While using `adapter.clear()` it works fine and clearing the list view.
- I am deleting the item from the array based on the position of the listview. I am able to  delete that item from the database but not from the `listview` immediately.  I am using adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); for updating but it not working. While using `adapter.clear()` it works fine and clearing the `list view`.

<-- spacer to keep code below out of the bulleted list above. -->

```
holder.dlttxt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Contact lContact = (Contact) list
                .getItemAtPosition(position);
        long positionid = list.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
        Log.e("", "--position id---" + positionid);

        Log.e("", "----deleted id--" + lContact.getID()
                + "--deleted name---" + lContact.getName());
        db.deleteContact(lContact.getID());
        quan = lContact.getName();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                lContact.getName() + ":" + "Deleted Sucessfully",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("", "---array size--" + imageArry.size());
        imageArry.remove(positionid);
        /*adapter.clear();
        adapter.addAll(db.getAllContacts());
        */                  
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        count = db.getContactsCount();
        HelperActivity.num.setText(String.valueOf(count));

    }

});
```

Comment: please post you adapter init..

Comment: because the adapter has a reference of the old data..so you might wona do it directly with the adapter or reset the data and notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: // Reading all contacts from database
List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
for (Contact cn : contacts) {
String log = "ID:" + cn.getID() + " Name: " + cn.getName()
     + " ,Image: " + cn.getImage() + "Price :" + cn.getprice();
id = cn.getID();
name = cn.getName();
price = cn.getprice();
getarray.add(cn.getName());
getid.add(cn.getID());
quantityid.add(cn.getQuantity());
pricesarray.add(cn.getprice());

imageArry.add(cn);

  }

adapter = new OrdersImageAdapter(this, R.layout.orderscart, imageArry);
  list.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: @yamuna : its better if u do it in `Activity` and use an *interface* for button click event.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can delete the item inside of your adapter getview method

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

-------------------------- inflating stuff etc.
holder.dlttxt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Contact lContact = (Contact) list
                .getItemAtPosition(position);
        long positionid = list.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
        Log.e("", "--position id---" + positionid);

        Log.e("", "----deleted id--" + lContact.getID()
                + "--deleted name---" + lContact.getName());
        db.deleteContact(lContact.getID());
        quan = lContact.getName();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                lContact.getName() + ":" + "Deleted Sucessfully",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("", "---array size--" + imageArry.size());
        imageArry.remove(positionid);
        /*adapter.clear();
        adapter.addAll(db.getAllContacts());
        */                  
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        count = db.getContactsCount();
        HelperActivity.num.setText(String.valueOf(count));

    }

});

}
```

Comment: Then where i need to delete?

Comment: where do you want. You can add onclickListener or touch listener to the item and when click or swipe the item will be removed automatically

Comment: i Have a remove bitton in my listview... When i am clicking that button i need to delete the that row from the listview

Comment: Ok. You can use a view holder holding the button component when click the button only you need a position of the raw. Then inside of button.onclick listener you can remove the row and notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: Yes when i am clicking the delete button i need to that row

Comment: where is your code snippet. Inside adapter or not. probably not  you call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  from outside of adapter. I am saying that you can delete the row inside of adapter easily by removing the related row. You can post your code then i fixed for you if your problem isnt solved.

Comment: will you please send ur mails id i will send this class to you

Comment: you are deleting latest item each item since position is not the position of the row you want to delete. in my code, final position in the getview method, you should use this as a position while deleting.

Comment: makaveli1903@yandex.com

Comment: Yeah i sent mail to you

Answer (score 0):

**notifyDataSetChanged() simply call this method remove adapter for the statement bc notifyDataSetChanged() is the method of the adapter and you are in side adapter's getView() Method **

**and one thing more this will not work properly you have to use tags to get the exactlocation  to delete **

```
 long positionid = list.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
```

Comment: In positionid I am getting the exact position is it wrong?

Comment: That bc your list might be small but in case of bigger list with bigger number of items cause unpredictable behaviour

Comment: does this solved your question notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I changed to notifyDataSetchanged() but it not working and replacing  long positionid = list.getItemIdAtPosition(position); with int positionid = (int) list.getItemIdAtPosition(position); now i am able to updating the listview but only lastitem is deleting every time....

Comment: Read about using tags in listView

Comment: I solved my problem by replacing notidydatasechanged() with  adapter = new OrdersImageAdapter(YourOrder.this, R.layout.orderscart, imageArry);
     list.setAdapter(adapter);
this line. I commented notifydatasetchanges();....

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `interface` for handling *click event* of that `delete` *Button*

**Code snippet**

`interface` for handling *click event*

```
public interface ListItemBtnClickInterface {

    public void listItemBtnClickListener(Object obj, int viewId);
}
```

code for *Constructor* of `Adapter`

```
public AddExpTypeAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        List<ExpenseTypeInfo> objects, ListItemBtnClickInterface _interface) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    _context = context;
    layoutId = resource;
    dataList = objects;
    this._interface = _interface;
    dbHelper = new PortfolioDbHelper(context);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

code for `Delete Button click` in Adapter after initialization

```
vieweHolder.deleteImgView.setTag(position);
vieweHolder.deleteImgView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Object data = v.getTag();
        if(data != null) {
            _interface.listItemBtnClickListener(data, v.getId());
        }
    }
});
```

code for Setting up adapter for `ListView` in `Activity`

```
addExpTypeAdapter = new AddExpTypeAdapter(AddExpTypeActivity.this, 
                R.layout.row_add_type, expTypeList, new ListItemBtnClickInterface() {

                private int clickedPosition;

                @Override
                public void listItemBtnClickListener(Object obj, int viewId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    clickedPosition = Integer.parseInt(obj.toString());
                    ExpenseTypeInfo expenseTypeInfo = expTypeList.get(clickedPosition);
                    final long expTypeId = expenseTypeInfo.getId();
                    switch (viewId) {
                        case R.id.deleteImgView:
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(AddExpTypeActivity.this)
                            .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.delete_exp_type_title))
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.delete_icon)
                            .setMessage(R.string.delete_exp_type_msg).setCancelable(true)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                dbHelper.deleteExpenseType(expTypeId);
                                dbHelper.closeDB();
                                expTypeList.remove(clickedPosition);
                                addExpTypeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        }).show();
                    break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
    typeListView.setAdapter(addExpTypeAdapter);
```

***N.B :-*** I'm using `ArrayAdapter` and please change those variable name with yours