# Calling start activity from adapter

Tags: android, android-intent, flags

I'm calling call activity from my adapter but getting below error -

```
11-29 13:10:41.193: E/AndroidRuntime(12623): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

code -

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+mMobileList.get(position)));
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
((Activity)mContext).startActivity(callIntent);
```

I have added FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK also.Still getting error.How to resolve it?

Comment: does your error changed when you added that Flag?

Comment: see this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4197135/3879470

Comment: @MohammedAli No use..

Comment: @yuvaツ is there any problem if u do it in `Activity` like [`this approach`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27104124/my-adapter-id-not-changes-while-notifydatasetchanged-also/27119122#27119122) instead of creating alert dialog use `intent` for call and don't need to `setFlag`

Comment: no. i'm displaying contacts in list view phone no. and email id.and want to perform operations on click of them

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
Intent dial = new Intent();
dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");
dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+strPhone1));
startActivity(dial);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: @yuvaツ then i think problem is rest of code not in intent

Comment: my rest code is fine..there is no problem..if there is problem it will not give error for FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: if this solution work than plz mark as right and  upvote

Comment: ohk than i delete this